# How tensorflow knows what variables to fit if I use classes from tf.layers package?

Tags: tensorflow

tf.layers package contains layer definition function, which does not contain explicit tensors to train. For example, [`layers.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) does not have `filter` tensor like [`nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) has.

How tensorflow finds variables to fit?

If I mix operations from `layers` and `nn` how can I provide my variables in the same way?

Suppose, I collect variables to train into list:

```
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([kernel_size[0], kernel_size[0], input_depth, filters],
                                              dtype=tf.float32, stddev=self.init_stddev), trainable=True)

    self.var_list.append(weights)

    biases = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filters], dtype=tf.float32, stddev=self.init_stddev), trainable=True)

    self.var_list.append(biases)

    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding=padding)

    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, biases)
```

and then

```
self.step = opt.minimize(self.cross_entropy, var_list=self.var_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused with your question. Of course tf.layers.conv2d has parameters for defining tensors(second one):

> tf.layers.conv2d
>   conv2d(
>       inputs,
>       filters,
>       kernel_size,
>       strides=(1, 1),
>       padding='valid',
>       data_format='channels_last',
>       dilation_rate=(1, 1),
>       activation=None,
>       use_bias=True,
>       kernel_initializer=None,
>       bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
>       kernel_regularizer=None,
>       bias_regularizer=None,
>       activity_regularizer=None,
>       kernel_constraint=None,
>       bias_constraint=None,
>       trainable=True,
>       name=None,
>       reuse=None
>   )

Also, in the tensorflow document, it was mentioned explicitly:

> tf.nn.conv2d - Computes a 2-D convolution given 4-D input and filter tensors.

So you should be using tf.layers.conv2d for building networks and tf.nn.conv2d for computations.

Comment: Second argument (`filters`) is integer. Apparently, tensor is created internally and added to trinable list of the graph.